# LPHW ex 41 - 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I have looked at the code and understand what line the issue is on, but for the life of me i can't figure out what to change to get this to get it to work.

When i run the code it throws an error after going through the first question / answer set ([quick link to th exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex41.html))  The error is:

file ex41.py line 73, in 
   question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
typeerror: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

I checked spelling, went through the code backwards and forwards, line by line comparing to the code i was copying, but i can't find the mistake to cause this.  I understand that for some reason "convert" which is defined on line 34, is for some reason returning no data..but i don't understand why.  Is it the 0 in range on line 41? I have no clue.  I have tried to fix this myself for more than a day..any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                    random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

        for sentence in snippet, phrase:
            result = sentence[:]

            #fake class names
            for word in class_names:
                result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

            #fake other names
            for word in other_names:
                result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

            #fake parameter lists
            for word in param_names:
                result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

            results.append(result)

        return results


#keep going until they hit ctrl-d
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print question
            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER: %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

Comment: try to copy/paste code from LPTHW website to simple notepad file. Try if it works. And also, are you using python 2?

Comment: yes, i'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

In Python, indentation matters.  Removing most of the code, we see

```
def convert(snippet, phrase):

    results = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):

        for sentence in snippet, phrase:

            results.append(result)

        return results
```

And from that you should see the problem.  You're returning `results` *inside* the `for i` loop.  This means that even if you got into the loop (say, because `snippet.count("@@@")` returned 2 or something), you'd return immediately after doing the `i==0` calculations.

And if `snippet.count("@@@")` is 0, you never `return` at all.  If a Python function finishes without executing an explicit `return`, it's treated as if you typed `return None`-- which is what you're getting, and what isn't iterable.

One way to have found this problem earlier would have been to add `print` all over the place: that lets you see what branches are being taken and which ones aren't, and makes it much easier to narrow things down.

Comment: thank you and *facepalm.*  I looked long and hard at that earlier today making sure that i hadn't mis spelled anything..i just totally missed the problem.  Thanks again!! :)

Comment: okay, i looked at the code i was copying, and it has the return in the same place i put it.  I moved it out of the for i loop and put it in line with the def convert indentation, it returned "need more than 0 value to unpack" i moved it to it's own line completely and it said "return outside function"  so..while i have a better understanding of what's going on - the code still isn't working.